# How am I able to implement an object oriented Binary Search Tree, based on an object key of String

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a specific Pokemon in a Binary Search Tree based on its name, my inOrder method to sort the Pokemon alphabetically works just fine. When I use that same logic to compare the Pokemon I'm looking for and the one in the Tree, it can't find it and I don't know how to fix it.

I've tried to use the compareTo method based on Strings to determine if the two comparing object's names are similar, but that may also have some flaws.

```
   class PokemonBST { 
        int comparisonCount = 0;


        class Node { 
            // int key;
            Pokemon key; 
            Node left, right; 

            //public Node(int item) { 
            public Node(Pokemon item) { 
                key = item; 
                left = right = null; 
            } 
        } 

        // Root of BST 
        Node root; 

        // Constructor 
        PokemonBST() { 
            root = null; 
        } 

        public Pokemon findPokemon(String name) {

            comparisonCount = 0;

            try {
                comparisonCount++;
                Pokemon temp = search(root, new Pokemon(name, 0, 0)).key;

                System.out.println("Comparisons made: " + comparisonCount);
                return temp;
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                System.out.println("Pokemon not found!");
                System.out.println("Comparisons made: " + comparisonCount);
                return null;
            }

        }


        public Node search(Node root, Pokemon key) 
        { 
            // Base Cases: root is null or key is present at root 
            if (root==null || root.key.getName()==key.getName()) 
                return root; 

            // val is greater than root's key 
            if (key.getName().compareTo(root.key.getName()) > 0) 
                return search(root.left, key); 

            // val is less than root's key 
            return search(root.right, key); 
        }
void insert(Pokemon key) { 
        root = insertRec(root, key); 
    } 

    /* A recursive function to insert a new key in BST */
    // TODO: What changes need to be made to work with Pokemon instead of int?
    Node insertRec(Node root, Pokemon key) { 
        /* If the tree is empty, return a new node */
        if (root == null) { 
            root = new Node(key); 
            return root; 
        } 

        /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
        if (key.getName().compareTo(root.key.getName()) < 0) 
            root.left = insertRec(root.left, key); 
        else if (key.getName().compareTo(root.key.getName()) > 0) 
            root.right = insertRec(root.right, key); 

        /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
        return root; 
    }

    // This method mainly calls InorderRec() 
    void inorder() { 
        inorderRec(root); 
    } 



    // A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST 
    void inorderRec(Node root) { 
        if (root != null) { 
            inorderRec(root.left); 
            System.out.println(root.key); 
            inorderRec(root.right); 
        } 
    } 

}
```

My Driver to test the BST:

```
public class PokemonBSTDriver {
    static PokemonBST myPokemonTree = new PokemonBST();
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        //TODO: Add code in the main method to perform desired tests
        readPokemonCSV();
        myPokemonTree.inorder();
        Pokemon found = myPokemonTree.findPokemon("Zubat");
        System.out.println(found);
} 

static void readPokemonCSV() {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    int pokemonCount = 0;
    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pokemon.csv"));


        String line = "";
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String[] pokemonDetails = line.split(",");

            if(pokemonDetails.length > 0 )
            {
                //Create a temporary pokemon
                Pokemon tempPokemon = new Pokemon();

                tempPokemon.setName(pokemonDetails[1]);
                tempPokemon.setSpeed(Integer.valueOf(pokemonDetails[10]));
                tempPokemon.setTotal(Integer.valueOf(pokemonDetails[4]));

                // Now we use the insert method in the BST to add in our pokemon
                myPokemonTree.insert(tempPokemon);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            br.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ie)
        {
            System.out.println("Error occured while closing the BufferedReader");
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // End of code adapted from Example 1. Using Buffered Reader and String.split() from https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

 }
}
```

I receive an ordered Tree of all the Pokemon I've added from a .csv file in alphabetical order showing that it can determine the characters of the Strings, however it cannot 'find' the specific Pokemon type.

```
public int compareTo(Pokemon pokemon) {

    int pokeKey = pokemon.getName().length();
    int key = this.name.length();

    if (pokeKey > key) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pokeKey < key) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return this.name.compareTo(pokemon.getName());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use equals() instead of ``` ==``if (root==null || root.key.getName().equals(key.getName()) ) ```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, however still no luck. There is a TO DO: tasked in my main method of the PokemonBSTDriver telling me to add code to perform the desired tests, however the code provided by my instructor seems to already do that, any ideas of what I should add if anything at all?

I've added the compareTo method to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

In your search method,  `root.key.getName()==key.getName()` is checking whether the two string variables point to same object or not. But what you need is comparing two strings character by character. So, you must use `equals()` method instead. Change the comparision to 
 `root.key.getName().equals(key.getName())`. Hope it solvable your problem!

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, however still no luck. There is a TO DO: tasked in my main method of the PokemonBSTDriver telling me to add code to perform the desired tests, however the code provided by my instructor seems to already do that, any ideas of what I should add if anything at all? I've added the compareTo method to my original question.